# Function that applies a function to list elements results in list options (SOME list1, SOME list2...), return one list option (SOME[list1, list2, ...]

Tags: sml

This question is from a beginner course, and in the abstract I can conceptualize it in quite a straightforward way, but I can't even begin to implement it in SML:

The goal is to write a curried function that takes another function and a list. The function passed in is applied to all the list elements, and returns OPTIONS. If a NONE option is ever returned, the overall function returns NONE. If a NONE option is not returned, the passed in function applied to the list elements will return SOME options, ie SOME listElement1, SOME listElement2, ..., and the overall function returns one list option of these list options values, ie SOME[listElement1, listElement2...] such that an empty list passed in would return SOME[].

I can understand the fundamental goal, but I can't seem to implement it.

At a very simple level I feel like I could just say simply, ok, pass in a curried function and list (ie `fun Example f lst =` ...) and pattern match on `f lst` such that if NONE is returned, return NONE, otherwise, get the option value and append it to a recursive call to `fun Example`, ie: `case f lst of NONE => NONE | SOME v => SOME[v @ fun Example` ...]. Obviously I'm missing something here though. Thanks so much.

Comment: So, this function `f` you're describing, takes two arguments: a function we'll call `g` and a `'a list` we'll call `lst`. The function `g` should take a value of type `'a` and returns a value of type `'b option`. If applying `g` to _any_ of them elements in `lst` yields `NONE`, the fucntion `f` should return `NONE`. Otherwise it should return a value of type `'b list option` constructed using `SOME`, such that the signature for `f` should be:  `('a -> 'b option) -> 'a list -> 'b list option`?

Comment: yes, exactly, thank you for replying.

Comment: This can be implemented with a fold. If your accumulator state is `NONE`, then it remains `NONE` (this will ensure that encountering one `NONE` result propagates to the end of the fold. If it's `SOME lst` _and_ the result of applying `g` to the current element is `NONE`, then update the accumulator state to `NONE`. But... if the accumulator state is `SOME lst` _and_ the result of  applying `g` to the current element is `SOME result`, then update the accumulator state to `SOME (result::lst)`.

Comment: Thank you! I had definitely considered fold, but I did not consider using NONE as the accumulator. I will try this.

Comment: Well, the output type of the accumulator is the type of the output for a fold, so if you start with `SOME []` you'll end up with a `list option` type.

Comment: Actually, in the end, I think the simplest solution was this: `fun all_answers f xs = case (List.filter (fn x=> f x = NONE) xs) of [ ] => SOME xs |_ => NONE`. This may be missing the point of the learning exercise, but it captures the end goal. Unfortunately, the wording of the question leaves it a bit unclear.

Answer (score 0):

As @ahpto has already found an answer and shared in comments, I feel comfortable posting a few suggestions.

First, let's look at solving this with a fold.

```
fun f g lst =
  let
    fun f'(_, NONE)        = NONE
      | f'(x, (SOME lst')) =
        case g x of
          NONE        => NONE
        | SOME result => SOME (result::lst')

    val init = SOME []
  in
    foldr f' init lst
  end;
```

If we evaluate:

```
f (fn x => if x mod 2 = 0 then NONE else SOME (x * 3 + 1)) [1,3,5]
```

We get:

```
SOME [4, 10, 16]
```

If we evaluate:

```
f (fn x => if x mod 2 = 0 then NONE else SOME (x * 3 + 1)) [1,2,3,5]
```

We get:

```
NONE
```

As for the solution posted by the OP in comments, `List.filter` will necessarily  iterate over the entire list, while `List.find` will not necessarily do so.

```
fun all_answers' f xs = 
  case List.find (fn x => f x = NONE) xs of   
    NONE   => SOME xs 
  | SOME _ => NONE;
```

Of course a major difference between the OP's approach and the one I've shown using a fold is that the latter preserves the value generated on each iteration if there are no `NONE` values returned.

Reimplementing the behavior shown with using a fold, using explicit recursion, we can write:

```
fun f _ []        = SOME []
  | f g (x::xs)   =
    case g x of
      NONE        => NONE
    | SOME result =>
      case f g xs of
        NONE      => NONE
      | SOME lst  => SOME (result::lst);
```

We know if the list is empty, the result will be `SOME []`.

If it's not empty, we check the value of evaluating `g x`. If this is `NONE`, the function returns `NONE`. If it's not, we use the pattern-matching to get the `result`, and then we check the return value of evaluating `f g xs`. If this is `NONE` then the function's return value will be `NONE`. If not, we use pattern-matching against to get the list that's returned, add the `result` to the front of that list.

We could make this look cleaner by evaluating both `g x` and `f g xs` and then matching on both results:

```
fun f g []                    = SOME []
  | f g (x::xs)               =
    case (g x, f g xs) of
      (NONE, _)               => NONE
    | (_, NONE)               => NONE
    | (SOME result, SOME lst) => SOME (result::lst);
```

But consider what happens if we evaluate:

```
f (fn x => if x mod 2 = 0 then NONE else SOME (x * 3 + 1)) [2,1,3,5];
```

In the previous implementation, the first element in the list will yield `NONE` and stop the recursion.

In the "cleaner" code, we have to evaluate the list `[1,3,5]`. Nothing in that list will yield `NONE`, so your program will run on the whole list, and the immediately throw that work away.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond to my post, it really helps me a great deal.